# If $X$ and $Z-X$ are independent, then $\mathbb E[s^Xt^{Z-X}] = \mathbb E[s^X] E[t^{Z-X}], \quad s,t \in [0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Z-X$ are independent, then $\mathbb E[s^Xt^{Z-X}] = \mathbb E[s^X] E[t^{Z-X}], \quad s,t \in [0,1]$

I think this is right, but I do not know how to show that. Any help?

Comment: how are $X$ and $Z-X$ independent?

Comment: Use $s^X=e^{X*log(s)}$ and the properties of the moment generating function

Comment: @Snoop What do you mean, how? If $X$ and $Y$ are any independent random variables, and $Z=Y+X$, then $X$ and $Z-X$ are independent.

Comment: @JamesMartin true

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera What propertiies of the moment generating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a special case of a much more general fact.

The definition of independence of random variables $X$ and $Y$ is that for all (measurable) sets $A$ and $B$, $\{X\in A\}$ and $\{Y\in B\}$ are independent events.

I'm assuming you're already happy with the following: if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$.

Now assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent and let $f$ and $g$ be any (measurable) functions. Then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent random variables. This is because $\{f(X)\in A\}=\{X\in f^{-1}(A)\}$ and $\{g(Y)\in B\}=\{Y\in g^{-1}(B)\}$, and
those two events are independent because of the indepdendence of $X$ and $Y$.

So we get $E(f(X)g(Y))=E(f(X))E(g(Y))$.

Now to get the property you want, take $Y=Z-X$, and consider the functions $f(x)=s^x$, and $g(y)=t^y$.

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. Apart from being against [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513), it is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their assessed homework, so giving them the complete answer is a kick in the teeth to the rest of their class.

Comment: @user1729 Fair point. Although please try to write in a more friendly way! - none of this business about my actions being like kicking people in the teeth. (Please yourself follow the advice in the post that you linked to!!) In defence of this particular question, I would say (i) the poster has a history of reasonable questions over a long period of time; (ii) it looks unlikely as a stand-alone exam question (although clearly it could be an intermediate step in a question). Anyway, I have no strong feelings about it, I'll delete the answer in due course.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I shouldn't have used that phrase.

Comment: @user1729 No worries! (And I discover I actually can't delete it once it's been accepted....)